# using Package name in main Class, causes NoClassFoundException

Tags: java

My code:

```
//package Foo;
public class Bar{
public static void main(String[] argv){System.out.println("test");}
}
```

now, when i compile and runn it, the code will work but, when i uncomment the first line it will throw an exception when i try to run it with

```
java Bar
```

it will throw the following:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Bar (wrong name: Foo/Bar)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

And when i try to run it this way:

java Foo.Bar

i will get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Foo.Bar
```

the same output will be generated when i do the Following:

```
java -classpath ./ Foo.Bar
```

even when i do specify the complete path to the current path , and i think it should not be neccesary but i did that, i still geht the message:" Could not find or load ...".

Comment: Post your folder structure and the folder where you're executing the command.

Comment: there is only this single file Bar.class nothing else, or what do you mean with folder structure?

Comment: Did you recompile your code after you changed it? Did `Foo` folder appear? From where you are invoking your `java -classpath ./ Foo.Bar` command?

Comment: from the same folder where the Bar.class lives, and yes i did recompile

Comment: "*from the same folder where the Bar.class lives*" do you mean `Foo` folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add package `Foo`, you should change also the folder structure:

```
 //before:
 ./Bar.java

 //after adding Foo package:
 ./Foo/Bar.java
```

Then you run it as follows:

```
./java Foo.Bar
```

(note: you should be in `.` directory, not `./Foo`)

Check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

A quote from the link above:

> ```
>  //in the Rectangle.java file 
>  package graphics;
>  public class Rectangle {
>     ... 
>  }
> ```
>
> Then, put the source file in a directory whose name reflects the name of the package to which the type belongs:
>
> ```
>  .....\graphics\Rectangle.java
> ```

Comment: Ok I did that, my Folder Structure is now as follows:

    /Foo/Bar.java
and
    /Foo/Bar.class 

like the Oracle doc describes it will also compile, but when i try to execute it, it will throw the same noclassdeffound exception or when i  cd to Foo, and type java Foo.Bar it will again say "Error: Could not find or load main class Foo.Bar"

Comment: Don't do cd to Foo, you should be in the same directory as the Foo directory is. See my edited response.